# Blogengine.net as a subdir to my website?

Tags: asp.net, blogengine.net

I already have a website running on my server and now I wanted to install Blogengine.net and have it running as a subdirectory to my website. I need it to be a subdirectory so I can check for authorization and use other stuff from my website that is already running.

I get this error if I not create a virtual directory for my blog:

"It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

How can I have BE running as a subdirectory without making it a virtual directory? How can I use the stuff like sessions, masterpages from my already running website?

Hope you understand what I'm talking about, my english is not the best. Sorry! :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Contents>IIS Settings then mark the folder that is mapped to your subdomain as virtual directory.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, but I did it via my hosting company (GoDaddy.com) as a "shared hosting" solution.

Basically, I have a primary domain (scottmarlowe.com) and, in a sub-folder off that main site, another site (itscodingtime.com) with its own domain but which exists as a sub-folder beneath the scottmarlowe.com root.

So, I have:

> root
>
> root \ itscodingtime

where "itscodingtime" is a whole other BlogEngine.NET blog.

I don't know if that answers your question or not, but it's how I did it.